# Return custom object from webservice

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, ejb

I have this situtation:

in MyEJBProject

```
@Stateless
class MyBean implements MyRemoteBean{

    @Override
    public String myFunction(){...}
}
```

and

```
@Remote
public interface MyRemoteBean{
    public String myFunction();
}
```

in MyWEBProject (with a reference to MyEJBProject), i have

```
@WebService
public class MyService{
    @EJB
    MyRemoteBean remoteBean;

    @WebMethod
    public String myWSFunction(){
        return remoteBean.myFunction();
    }
}
```

This works great.
But now "myFunction" has to return a custom object, let's say MyResponse. I created a MyResponse class (implements serializable) and changed the firm of the function on all the classes, but when i deploy the solution on WAS7, i get an error telling me that the wsdl cannot be generated.
i have searched for this problem and found that could be many different things. I'm i missing something? some annotation or property?

thanks in advance

**EDIT**

my custom object is simply

```
public class MyResponse implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = ...
    ...
    some other String and long variables
}
```

so the code would be:

```
@Stateless
class MyBean implements MyRemoteBean{

    @Override
    public MyResponse myFunction(){...}
}

@Remote
public interface MyRemoteBean{
    public MyResponse myFunction();
}

@WebService
public class MyService{
    @EJB
    MyRemoteBean remoteBean;

    @WebMethod
    public MyResponse myWSFunction(){
        return remoteBean.myFunction();
    }
}
```

The relevant (not so) stacktrace is

```
WSWS7054E: The Web Services Description Language (WSDL) file could not be generated for the [MyService] Web service implementation class because of the following error: java.lang.Exception: A WSDL Definition could not be generated for the implementation class: [MyService]
WSWS7027E: JAX-WS Service Descriptions could not be correctly built because of the following error: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: WSWS7054E: The Web Services Description Language (WSDL) file could not be generated for the [MyService] Web service implementation class because of the following error: java.lang.Exception: A WSDL Definition could not be generated for the implementation class: [MyService]
```

Comment: please post the full stack trace and the definition of your custom object

Comment: Post the content of MyResponse too.